# why does my pivot give me an error?

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'FullName'.

```
select FullName, 
['1-Urgent'], ['2-High'], ['3-Medium (3000)']
from (select FullName,AltBusinessSeverity, total from Mdata) AS ST
PIVOT (
min(FullName) FOR  AltBusinessSeverity in (['1-Urgent'], ['2-High'], ['3-Medium (3000)'])
) AS PT
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show `total` as your data, then you need to do the following:

```
select FullName, 
['1-Urgent'], ['2-High'], ['3-Medium (3000)']
from (select FullName,AltBusinessSeverity, total from Mdata) AS ST
PIVOT (
min(total) FOR  AltBusinessSeverity in (['1-Urgent'], ['2-High'], ['3-Medium (3000)'])
) AS PT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the FullName as a `SELECT` from the `PIVOT` and as the aggregate. You need this:

```
select FullName, 
['1-Urgent'], ['2-High'], ['3-Medium (3000)']
from (select FullName,AltBusinessSeverity, count(*) AS total from Mdata) AS ST
PIVOT (
SUM(Total) FOR  AltBusinessSeverity in (['1-Urgent'], ['2-High'], ['3-Medium (3000)'])
) AS PVT
```

Comment: this works but the totals come back as null. also i dont want a sum, i want to show the number in the total field as it is without modification for each severity level by each fullName row.

Comment: @kacalapy maybe you want to show some sample data then? (Like build a temp table that people can work from, and give us the create-table and insert-data for us to work with that?)

Comment: @kacalapy, check the edited query. Without sample data as @jcolebrand pointed out it's hard to tell why it returns `NULLS`. However, in general with a `PIVOT` the inner `SELECT` needs to contain all of the fields you need in the `PIVOT`. One of those fields must be used in an aggregate within the `PIVOT` statement. Another field must be used after the `FOR` to designate the fields that are used to `PIVOT`. Neither of those fields may be used in the outer `SELECT` - instead, the values you place in the brackets will appear as columns, with the aggregate for values.